JavaScript - Steam API running into a CORS policy that blocks fetching
After some digging I found a Steam API that actually gets me data, I was trying to build a Steam clone but I can't access any of the data through a Fetch (I can paste the link in my browser and it'll show the JSON data).
fetch('https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=420', {
mode:  'cors' ,
headers: {
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*'
},
})
 .then(response => response.json())
  .catch(error => console.error(error));

I tried changing the mode to 'no-cors' but same error.

Admittedly, I'm new with working with APIs and after an hour of googling around for fixes to this CORS policy error, I couldn't get anything to work.
Also, if there's a better Steam API out there for the storefront and individual games, I'd be very interested.

CORS headers are set by the server, not the client. You can't change them or work around them, that's the whole point. You should make your requests from the server, not from the browser.
